# How to print this pattern of stars in php?

Tags: php, for-loop, conditional-statements

Input n
Height=2*n+1;

```
if n=1
 *
**
 *

if n=2
        *
  *     *
* * * * *
  *     *
        *

if n=3
                *
        *       *
  *     *       *
* * * * * * * * *
  *     *       *
        *       *
                *
```

and so on...

thare is a gap of 'n' stars between the two vertical lines of stars.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: gotta love pseudo code huh? So... did y'all try anything? this is pretty much a no brainer.

Comment: I hope you're not waiting for someone to write that out for you, are you? Edit: Yeah, you're waiting; keep waiting then.

Comment: I'm, definitely not doing your homework. Hint: 2 for loops.

Comment: Should even be possible to do it in one for loop with a little bit of math

Comment: `function tree($limit) {
    $length = array_sum(range(1, $limit)) + $limit;
    $partial = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $limit; ++$i) {
        $partial[] = str_pad(preg_replace_callback('/\d/', function($value) use ($limit) { return str_repeat(' ', $limit - $value[0]+1) . '*'; }, implode(range($i, 1))), $length, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    $result = array_merge($partial, [str_repeat('*', $length)], array_reverse($partial));
    array_walk($result, function($value) { echo $value, PHP_EOL; });
}


$limit = 3;

tree(3);`

Answer (score 1):

Yummy foreach:

```
<?php
function draw_stars($n)
{
    foreach(range(1, $n) as $i) {
        foreach(range(1, $i) as $k)
            $pattern[] = '*';
        $pattern[] = str_repeat('*', 2 * $i + 1);
    }
    foreach($pattern as $k => $stars)
        $pattern[$k] = str_split(
            str_pad($stars, 2 * $n + 1, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH)
        );
    $pattern = transpose($pattern);
    foreach($pattern as $line)
        echo implode('', $line), "\n";
}
function transpose($array) {
    return array_map(null, ...$array);
}
```